# ios iphone scrollview loading partially scrolled

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

So I have an iOS app I am working on and I'm running into a problem with a `UIScrollView` and its contents.  Here are a couple screen shots for when the view loads in both portrait and landscape

portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

As you can see, the contents load in odd positions in the `UIScrollView`.  The contents of the `UIScrollView` are loading as if they have already been partially scrolled.  for the portrait I was going for displaying the entirety of the `UIScrollView` since there are only the two inner `UIView`.  and then for the landscape showing the first inner `UIView` and then allow the user to "sroll" to the bottom `UIView`.

I can't seem to get these to cooperate.  Any suggestions for how to get this to work?

in my implementation file I have:

```
myScrollView.delegate = self;
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthVal, heightVal);
[myScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointZero animated: NO];
```

Comment: Use two storybord one for pot-rate  and one for landscape and then switch its frame to each other in - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what is causing the issue since you haven't given much info about your implementation.

But you can easily force the `UIScrollView` to start on top by using `[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero NO];`.

Where to put this call depends on your implementation, but if you're using regular `UIViewControllers`, `viewDidLoad` would be an appropriate place.

Comment: I've updated the question to have the implementation file contents related to the `UIScrollView`.  Let me know if there's anything else that you think is missing that should be up there.

Comment: Unfortunately that is still not enough to understand what is happening. To fully understand the behavior we have to know what happens to the whole view, the autosizing mask being used and if there's any on rotation delegate methods.

Comment: PS.: did setting the content offset manually have any effect?

Comment: No it didn't.  i think it's something else giving me troubles.  I had to do a lot of things to get this to work in iOS 6 and now that I've moved to iOS 7 things have gone all wonky... and it's been long enough I'm not entirely sure what all I had done to get this all to work.

Comment: I'll try to get all the info you wanted, but it'll probably be tomorrow before I can get it.  forgive me for being a little .... late in responses.